# Pass XML in SOAP request in a tag in proper format-preferably in CDATA envelope

Tags: soap-api, xml

I have a requirement to pass XML as a string into SOAP request to an external system. I am generating an XML using DOM.Document class, but when I am sending it in SOAP request, it gets encoded with `<` replaced with `&lt;`

I tried to envelope in CDATA using:

```
XmlStreamWriter xsw = new XmlStreamWriter();
xsw.writeCData(xml)
```

but with no luck. Even the `<` in `CDATA` envelope is getting encoded.

Please let me know if there is any method to pass the XML without being encoded.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this code:

```
XmlStreamWriter xsw =new XmlStreamWriter();
xsw.writeStartElement(null, 'x', null);
xsw.writeCData('<y>abc</y>');
xsw.writeEndElement();
System.debug(xsw.getXmlString());
```

it outputs:

```
<x><![CDATA[<y>abc</y>]]></x>
```

which is what I think you are looking for, the embedded XML wrapped in CDATA.

Comment: Hi, Keith, that is true. When I  see in my debug logs, things shows up correctly. However, only when I pass this to a service and trace the payload in RequestBin, I see all "<" getting encoded.

Comment: @DeepSinghal Perhaps RequestBin encodes for presentation purposes? In my experience the text that you emit in an Apex HTTP request does not undergo any further encoding within Salesforce.